# select column twice of same table on different condtion Psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo, odoo-11

I'm working on Odoo11 and using psql. And I want to select the same column twice for the same table on a different condition, For this, I'm using case statement And I got the output, but not as expected. Because I want output in a single row but it comes in two rows.

**Query**

```
 SELECT project_id,
    CASE WHEN project_type = 'Internal'  THEN SUM(unit_amount) END,
    CASE WHEN project_type = 'Project' THEN SUM(unit_amount) END 
FROM account_analytic_line where project_id = 347 GROUP BY project_id,project_type
```

*Output Screenshot:*
[image]

For above screenshot, it generates two rows for the same project_id and wants these columns in a single row for the same project_id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your input data (please do not use screenshots!). I assume that project_type is different.

Comment: project_type is selection field project_type = fields.Selection([('Project', 'Project'), ('Internal', 'Internal')], 'Type')

Comment: user can fill timesheet as project hours or internal hours.

Comment: Is there a reason for grouping by project_type?

Comment: yes, because I want to calculate hours where employee has taken actual project hours and internal hours in that project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get the result in a single row, you can use window functions:

```
select distinct on (project_id)
project_id,
sum(unit_amount) FILTER (where project_type = 'Internal') over(PARTITION BY project_id) as intern, 
sum(unit_amount) FILTER (where project_type = 'Project') over(PARTITION BY project_id) as project
FROM account_analytic_line
```

extend with a fitting where clause.